# SQL Unable to Convert Varchar to Numeric - Conversion failed error

Tags: sql, casting, numeric, varchar

I need to convert serial numbers in a database table to show as numeric or int. I have attempted to convert them but it does not seem to like certain values like the following:  1.02253e+007. Getting an error stating:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.02253e+007' to
>   data type int.

Is there something I am leaving out? Any help much appreciated

```
SELECT  [ID]
  ,[SalesOrder]
  ,[JobNumber]
  ,[StockCode]
  ,SerialNumber
  ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(16, 0), CAST(CASE 
                                  WHEN ISNUMERIC(SerialNumber) = 1 THEN 
                                  SerialNumber 
                                  ELSE 0 
                                END AS FLOAT))
```

Receiving error:
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.02253e+007' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

The `case` is returning an integer, which is your problem.  You are doing lots of intermediate conversions that are not necessary.  Just do:

```
(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SerialNumber) = 1
      THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(16, 0), SerialNumber)
      ELSE 0 
 END)
```

Or better yet:

```
COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(16, 0), SerialNumber), 0)
```

If you need to support exponential values (such as 1.02253e+007), then you do need the intermediate conversion to float:

```
TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(16, 0), 
            COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(float, SerialNumber), 0)
           )
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, getting error Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to numeric after attempting the code supplied

Comment: @Acc . . . The error is from a different part of the code.  If you are using `TRY_CONVERT()`, then you cannot be getting that error.

Comment: For try_convert i keep getting 'NUMERIC' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @ACC . . . `numeric` is not being used as a function.  You can use `decimal` instead; they are equivalent.